# Call pure javascript function from Angular 2 component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have one file that have dozens javascript functions. What I want to do is to import that file into Angular 2 component and run init() function that is defined in "external.js" file.

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

import "../../../../assets/external.js";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class ComponentNameComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor() { }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      // invoke init() function from external.js file
    }
}
```

external.js is loaded using import and in ngAfterViewInit() I want to invoke init() function that is in external.js that calls all other methods in that external file.

Here is part of external.js:

```
function init() {
  callFunction1();
  callFunction2();
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can import and declare your external object. after then you can use it in your component.

```
import 'external.js'
declare var myExtObject: any;
```

I made an example in plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/4CrShwpZrDxt1f1M1Bv8?p=preview

Hope this helps.

Comment: I followed your example. I created `var webGlObject = (function() {

    return {
        init: function() {
            init();
        }
    }

})(webGlObject||{})
`
and in ngAfterViewInit() tried to access with `       webGlObject.init();`

but I'm getting error
 `errors.service.ts:29 ReferenceError: webGlObject is not defined`

Comment: I have updated plunker with your webGlObject and it is working. Only thing I have changed is that you are calling init() in init function.

Comment: if you still get an error could you provide more information or create in for example in plunker, jsfiddle or something else?

Comment: the problem was because my script external.js was imported on the way that I described above. I move it to index.html and include it via <script> tag in header.After that it started to work.Thank you @hakany

Comment: This script seem to run when you move the js file to index.html. But the browser still complains `ReferenceError: webGlObject is not defined`. The solution for me was adding all the JS files under `scripts` in `angular-cli.json`

Comment: I followed your examples. I receive   TypeError: pm.loading is not a function. Loading is basically you func1 from plnkr example.

Comment: In angular 4 and 5 you can import the javascript using: import {filename} '../file/location/filename.js';

Comment: plunker unpkg.com references are not there anymore (404).

Answer (score 7):

Checkout my git project of angular 6 - I used this in login component -

https://github.com/gajender1995/Angular-HighChart-Auth

**exter.js**

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports){
   exports.value = "aaa";
   exports.gajender = function(){console.log(2)}; 
});
```

**login.component.ts**

```
 import * as MyModule from './exter.js';

 console.log('my value is', MyModule.gajender());
```

In **tsconfig** Add

```
"allowJs": true
```

Comment: Thanks for the superb answer mate. FYI, it did work without adding "allowJs" true in the tsconfig.json. Thank you :)

Comment: Getting `error TS2339: Property 'gajender' does not exist on type '{ (options: any): never; get: (options: any, callback: any) => void; getPromise: (options: any) =...'.`

Comment: define is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the javascript file like this:

```
import * as myjsname from '../../mypathto/myjavascriptfile.js';
```

You invoke a routine from the javascript file like this:

```
myjsname.myjsroutine();
```

Important, you need to use the export keyword in the javascript file like this:

```
export function myjsroutine() {
  //my js code
}
```